# Send page as an email through javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Internet explorer has a menu option which can be used to send a page as an email. Is it possible to invoke that function through javascript?

**Edit**

No, it's NOT a duplicate. I'm asking specifically for Internet Explorer and not javascript in general. MS might have added that feature to javascript in IE. I really do not care if it will not work in other browsers since it's an intranet app and all users must use IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of possible javascript calls to external Internet Explorer items.

[external Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535246%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There is currently no SendPageAsEmail available

So the answer to your question is "Not unless you use a plugin" for example something like

[IE Addon - Send selected text as email to anyone in Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jscript/archive/2007/01/31/ie-addon-send-selected-text-as-email-to-anyone-in-internet-explorer.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

No. Javascript has no way of sending an email directly.

Now you can use Javascript to communicate to a server side language, like PHP, and let the server send an email.

Answer (score -1):

Nope, Javascript doesn't have the facility to send email, you need a server side programming languge like asp or php.

Comment: So what you are saying now is, can IE send a page as an email, and if so, can you use JavaScript to trigger this?

Comment: IE ***can*** send a page as an email. It's a menu option in the "File" menu. I'm asking if I can trigger that option through javascript.